# How do change state when time change in use Pomdoro Clock as component in form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, clock

i make Pomodoro Clock as component for poroje ,i use it for several page , i need some action in form when seconde or minuter under some number , 
for example i use it in form , i need when my minute > 5 , my state change in form or other form when seconde >20 change state for this form, 
you can see my code form pomodoro clock in code pen :
 you can see my form in page i need when seconde>10 , in state , disable:false

https://codepen.io/soodeh/pen/qzNooP

```
class Test extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            sec: '30',
            disabled:true,
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
                <div className="row justify-content-center mt-3 h3">
                        <PomodoroClock sec={this.state.sec} numberSecEx={'25'} />
 <button
     type={"confirm"}
     width={300}
     disabled={this.state.disabled}/>
                </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood is that you are passing the seconds to the child component (PomodoroClock), which is changing its value. Now on some specific value, you want to change the state in parent. 
For this you should define a function in parent(Test) which will update your state and pass that function to child component and call it from child when the seconds reach the desired value.